# hibernate restrictions.in when the list of strings have special characters

Tags: hibernate, criteria

I need to write a query to check if a list of strings exist in a column. The list of strings have special characters like comma. I wrote Hibernate criteria

```
Restrictions.in("systemname", systemNameslist)
```

As systemNameslist strings have comma in some of them, the query output is incorrect, how can i get correct resultset

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please try this code once.It should work.

String[] systemNameslist = { "test1", "test2" };

Restrictions.in("systemname", systemNameslist )

Let me know it works for you or not